# Does a back-end user need a "writer" security role in Microsoft Dynamics just to add internal comments?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, crm, security-roles

Back-end user (analyst) needs access to type comments for co-workers when reviewing applications submitted by end-users (applicants). However, back-end user (analyst) should not have access to change information/ data submitted by end-users (applicants). Does the back-end user (analyst) need "writer" access under security roles just to leave comments?

Nothing has been tried, this is to be included in the business requirements document.